# Get value of Material-UI Select within form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get the currently selected value of a Material-UI `Select` component within `form` component, but I can't figure out what the proper way is, here is what I have tried:

```
<form onSubmit={handleCreateNewItem}>
  <TextField id="name" label="Name" />
  ...more text fields...
  <Select id="typeOfQuantity">
    {typesOfQuantities.map((menuItem) => (
      <MenuItem value={menuItem}>{menuItem}</MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>

  <IconButton type="submit">
    <DoneIcon />
    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
      Add
    </Typography>
  </IconButton>
</form>
```

And the `handleCreateNewItem`:

```
const handleCreateNewItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { name, typeOfQuantity, ...restOfFormFields} = e.target.elements;

  console.log(typeOfQuantity);
};
```

But `typeOfQuantity` is undefined. I am not using a separate onChange, because there are multiple fields on the form.

Do I have to create its own separate `onChange` handler and keep its reference? It would probably work, but it seems like a bad way to do it...

I have just tried with a pure html form and select and it works without issues:

```
const handleCreateNewItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { name, typeOfQuantity, ...restOfFields } = e.target.elements;

  console.log(name.value);
  console.log(typeOfQuantity.value);
};

<form onSubmit={handleCreateNewItem}>
  <select id="typeOfQuantity">
    {typesOfQuantities.map((menuItem) => (
      <option value={menuItem}>{menuItem}</option>
    ))}
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onChange`. Then set the value, which will then be capturable in your form.

```
const [ value, setValue ] = useState('');


    const handleCreateNewItem = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setValue(e.target.value)
    };

    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleCreateNewItem}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

Comment: Okay, maybe I shouldnt' have left the other stuff out, I have more than just the Select within the form, I have other text fields and such, that is why the onSubmit is on the form itself

Comment: Posting a incomplete question will yield you a incomplete answer. Simple as that. See edited answer where you return the value to the select element, which will be capturable in your form.

Comment: I know that and I have made the changes to reflect it, sorry:) and I saw the updated answer, still that seems like too much work to me, surely there must be a cleaner way of doing this, what if I have 10 different Selects, do I have to keep 10 states/references for each of them? P.S. with the same code I have no trouble doing it with pure html form.

Comment: Then use uncontrolled. Leave out the value, and leave out onChange. Set native={true}.

Comment: Just tried, now that makes the `MenuItem` not work, the drop down just shows one tiny black field which cant be selected. `EDIT:` found the code for `NativeSelect` on the documentation, have to use `option` instead of `MenuItem`

Comment: Thanks, I can move on now :) update your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

When the fields are much, I suggest you use Formik, it makes it simpler just as you said, you can check it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).